# 6 cells 3*2 grid layout with divs

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I am wondering what is the best way to create this 3*2 "table" using DIVS?

[image: simple 3*2 grid layout]

I am really tempted to use simple tables code

```
<table>
```

as it would be easier, but the trend today is to use Divs.
Therefore, what would be the best, elegant way to create something like this?

I always wondered why tables suddenly disappeared, I used to create websites using only tables (time ago).

Comment: What is going inside the boxes???

Comment: If you're displaying tabular data (like you'd find in a spreadsheet) then absolutely use a table. For layout and design, divs are the way to go.

Comment: Use CSS styles to simulate a table. Unless it's a data grid, in which case use a table.

Comment: Andrew is  asking the right question, what's going in there?
If it's actual data which needs to be formatted,.. like well a table, then go with that! Forget trends, be practical.

Comment: I wouldn't follow trends, but just consider function and base my choice upon that.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the message. There will be website content (images and structure for the website) therefore I think i should use divs and not table.

Comment: @wicker95 Thanks, I agree with you, totally, but I noticed developers hating tables nowadays, as if they were used only for old technology websites..

Comment: @user2314737, same here. But still, I feel that tables looks too old today. Thank you

Comment: @MaRco85 Now you're seriously underestimating tables. Tables are wonderful, versatile, multi-purpose things that have gotten an undeserved bad rep in the last few years, and I really don't know why. I've seen people go so far as to invent new tag names that they style with CSS, just to avoid writing `<table>` in their source. So wrong. Anyway, if you want to structure your website, I presume with things like side bars and the like, don't use tables. Use something responsive, like inline or floating blocks.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `<table>` when you are, in fact, creating a table.  The only reason people say "use <div> instead of <table>" is because people used to format everything using <table>.  You are a creating a table, so use `<table>`.

Comment: I will admit that my first reaction to seeing tables used in HTML is usually bad, but there are valid uses. Search results with a lot of attached data points? Great use. Menu bars on top of the page? Bad example. There's a time and place, and we should all be careful about knee jerk reactions.

Comment: "There's nothing wrong with using <table> when you are, in fact, creating a table." sorry @andy-lester , but this made me smile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest answer:

```css
div {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: it's actually very simple. I didn't think about the 33% and I was wondering how to break the line after 3 divs... nice thanks!

Comment: Note that this will break if the container is smaller than 600px wide because of the border. You can avoid it with `box-sizing:border-box;`

Answer (score 2):

If you can get away with only having to support IE10+, you can use flexbox:

```css
*,*:before,*:after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.cell{
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

pen here if you want to play around with it - http://codepen.io/braican/pen/QbdbYb

Comment: Thank you! It's surely a good solution, cross-browser but I think the other one looks more professional (elegant). Thanks anyway! :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can also use https://jsfiddle.net/ftwn8q7w/1/

```
<div class="raw">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
<div class="raw">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>

.raw{
     display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.col{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: That won't preserve the widths of the columns.